# "for loop" error in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop to add up the sum between 2 integers
2-9=2+3+4+5...+9
and I used if statement to determine the larger integer in the input.
Somehow, the for will execute itself once even though if condition return a false value.
Therefore I keep getting the wrong value
Here is the code I wrote.
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int in1, in2;
    void accumulate_sum(int i1, int i2);
    cout<<"Enter two integer:"<<endl;
    cout<<"Integer 1:"<<endl;
    cin>>in1;
    cout<<"Integer 2:"<<endl;
    cin>>in2;
    accumulate_sum(in1, in2);
    return 0;
}

void accumulate_sum(int i1, int i2){
    int i, sum, ca;
    if (i1 > i2)
    {
        ca=1;
        for (i=i2;i<(i1+1); i++) {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    else {
        i=i1;
        for (i;i<(i2+1); i++) {
            sum+=i;

        }
    }
    switch (ca) {
        case 1:
            cout<<"the sume from "<<i2<<" to "<<i1<<" is "<<sum<<endl;
            break;

        default:     cout<<"the sume from "<<i1<<" to "<<i2<<" is "<<sum<<endl;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `else` branch leaves `ca` uninitialized.

Comment: Why do you think the for loop is executing once? What is your actual output?

Comment: I suggest you use more descriptive names. I have no idea what the difference between `i`, `i1`, and `i2`. Maybe `min` and `max`?

Comment: Where do you initialize `sum` and `ca`?

Comment: A word of advice.. you are repeating code when you do this using an `if` statement. You have two `for` loops that are essentially the same except for the direction of the indexer `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple solution:**

The problem in your program exists because you aren't initializing `sum` to before you start adding values.  You also check against `ca` in your switch even though there are paths where it's left uninitialized. Set them both to `0` where you declare them and everything should work.

---

**Further Improvements/Things to ponder:**

To improve, storing the min and max values can make your function a lot prettier and faster:

```
void accumulate_sum(int i1, int i2) {
    int sum = 0;
    int min = i1;
    int max = i2;
    if (i1 > i2) {
        min = i2;
        max = i1;
    }

    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        sum += i;

    cout << "the sum from " << min << " to " << max " is " << sum << endl;
}
```

Using the [science of partial sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Partial_sums), you can rewrite your `for` with a single formula.
Since the sum of all natural numbers between 1 and `n` can be simplified as...

[image]

and we can prove that the sum of all natural numbers from `min` to `max` is equivalent to ( ( (sum from 1 to `max`) - (the sum from 1 to `min`) ) + `min`)...

[image]

then we can replace our `for` loop with the formula...

[image]

```
void accumulate_sum(int i1, int i2) {
    int min = i1;
    int max = i2;
    if (i1 > i2) {
        min = i2;
        max = i1;
    }

    int sum = (max*(max+1))/2 - (min*(min+1))/2 + min;
    cout << "the sum from " << min << " to " << max " is " << sum << endl;
}
```

Also, it's good practice to declare your functions outside of `main()` unless you have a really good reason for doing so:

```
// ...
using namespace std;
void accumulate_sum(int i1, int i2);
void main() {
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Initializing the sum before the for loop does solve the problem. But I don't understand why not initializing sum would cause a problem to the for loop? Could you further elaborate how the problem occurred? Thanks!

Comment: @JunWeiSu Not initializing `sum` or `ca` will result in undefined behavior.  I ran the program to test it out and sum started with a value of -1208719637 while `ca` held a similar value.  Any time you do anything with these variables you'll continue to get undefined behavior.  Your `for` loops are written fine (although a little sloppy) and shouldn't fail when you fix your variable initializations.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a mathematical formula to sum all the numbers from n to m, like this:

[formula http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140916/latex_63cded397d9f50846f8c3c9e55e4af01_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140916/latex_63cded397d9f50846f8c3c9e55e4af01_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

Applying this formula makes your code much faster and cleaner, like so:

```
template <class T>
T accumulate_sum(T n, T m) {
    if (m<n) std::swap(n, m);
    return (m*(m+1))/2 - (n*(n+1))/2 + n;
}
```

Of course the template is not necessary, but if you call the function with an unsigned integer type, then casting it to `int` (which is signed) inside the function is not a good idea.

Be type safe (don't do unsigned-signed (or vice versa) conversions if possible), avoid unnecessary raw loops, and always use STL if you can!
I'm not a C++ expert (and neither trying to pretend like I am), but it's good to keep these in mind!

Cheers

Comment: Actually there is much simpler formula `(n+m)*(m-n+1)/2`

Comment: @Slava Even though you're right, it doesn't matter at the end. The optimizer in any half-decent compiler will get rid of any unnecessary operations. They give _exactly the same assembly code_ (as observed with g++ 5.2.1 using -O3 optimization), so it doesn't matter really. That formula seems simpler, I'll give you that, but it wouldn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
accumulate_sum(int integer1, int integer2){
     int min = integer1 < integer2 ? integer1 : integer2;
     int max = integer1 > integer2 ? integer1 : integer2;
     int sum = 0;
     for (int i = min; i < max; ++i){
          sum += i;
     }

     cout << "the sum of integers from " << min << " to " << max << " is " << sum;
}
```

you then eliminate the if and else statements and only have to write code once.